# How would you produce the following exact hexagon?

Tags: diagrams

I'm somewhat familiar with the array environment, but I'm not sure what the best approach would be to produce this diagram:

[image]

How would I make this, or diagrams similar to this? The slanted arrows and the positioning are what mainly throw me off.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use TikZ to draw that diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \def\radius{2cm} % change to an appropriate value
    \node (h0A) at (60:\radius)   {$H^0(A)$};
    \node (h0C) at (0:\radius)    {$H^0(C)$};
    \node (h1B) at (-60:\radius)  {$H^1(B)$};
    \node (h1A) at (-120:\radius) {$H^1(A)$};
    \node (h1C) at (180:\radius)  {$H^1(C)$};
    \node (h0B) at (120:\radius)  {$H^0(B)$};

    \path[->,font=\small]
        (h0A) edge node[auto] {$g_0$} (h0C)
        (h0C) edge node[auto] {$\delta_0$} (h1B)
        (h1B) edge node[auto] {$f_1$} (h1A)
        (h1A) edge node[auto] {$g_1$} (h1C)
        (h1C) edge node[auto] {$\delta_1$} (h0B)
        (h0B) edge node[auto] {$f_0$} (h0A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First the 6 vertices are defined (as *nodes* in TikZ-speak) using polar coordinates. They are named `(h0A)` to `(h0B)`. Then the arrows are drawn using `edge` paths (`(start) edge (finish)`) and the descriptions (again nodes) are placed beside them with `node[auto] {text}`.

[image: result]

A nice introduction to drawing commutative diagrams with TikZ is [*Commutative Diagrams with TikZ*](http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf).

Comment: Is there a way to produce "proper" arrow tips? These arrows don't mix well with `\to`, at least with CM fonts.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe you like it better without `>=latex`.

Comment: These both look very nice, thanks. Thanks for the pdf, I need to get around to learning TikZ soon.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way with Xy-pic

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C-1em{
& H^0(B) \ar[rr]^{f_0} && H^0(A) \ar[dr]^{g_0} \\
H^1(C) \ar[ur]^{\delta_1} &&&& H^0(C) \ar[dl]^{\delta_0} \\
& H^1(A) \ar[ul]^{g_1} && H^1(B) \ar[ll]^{f_1}
}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Remember to put the `\xymatrix` inside a `gathered` environment if you need an equation number next to it. Otherwise discard the `gathered` environment.

[image]

I've reduced the column distance and doubled the middle arrow across an empty column to keep uniform the arrow lengths.

##### Update

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{tikzcd}
  & H^0(B) \arrow[r,"f_0"] &[1em] H^0(A) \arrow[dr,"g_0"] \\
H^1(C) \arrow[ur,"\delta_1"] &&& H^0(C) \arrow[dl,"\delta_0"] \\
  & H^1(A) \arrow[ul,"g_1"] & H^1(B) \arrow[l,"f_1"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will be using `gathered` like that literally  times

Answer (score 5):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\def\R{2.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!10](-3,-3)(3,3)
\psset{nodesep=3pt,arrows=->,shortput=nab}\degrees[6]
\psnode(\R;0){P0}{$H^0(C)$} \psnode(\R;1){P1}{$H^0(B)$}
\psnode(\R;2){P2}{$H^0(B)$} \psnode(\R;3){P3}{$H^1(C)$}
\psnode(\R;4){P4}{$H^1(A)$} \psnode(\R;5){P5}{$H^1(B)$}
\ncline{P0}{P5}^{$\delta_0$}\ncline{P5}{P4}^{$f_1$}
\ncline{P4}{P3}^{$g_1$}     \ncline{P3}{P2}^{$\delta_1$}
\ncline{P2}{P1}^{$f_0$}     \ncline{P1}{P0}^{$g_0$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fear I have been beaten...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% define matrix
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3em, row sep=3em]
{  & $H^{0}(B)$ & $H^{0}(A)$ &\\
$H^{1}(C)$ &  &  &  $H^{0}(C)$ \\
 & $H^{1}(A)$ & $H^{1}(B)$ & \\};

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-1) edge node[above] {$\delta_{1}$} (m-1-2);

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-2) edge node[above] {$f_{0}$} (m-1-3);

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[above] {$g_{0}$} (m-2-4);

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-3-3) edge node[below] {$f_{0}$} (m-3-2);

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-4) edge node[below] {$\delta_{0}$} (m-3-3);

\path[->, font=\scriptsize]
(m-3-2) edge node[below] {$g_{1}$} (m-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution from Caramdir is much nicer than mine!

Comment: Please crop your image -- all that extra white space is not adding any information.

Comment: Done – sorry for not cropping

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `PSTricks`, see below. As always, there's more than way to do this!

See the `pst-node` documentation for more details and plenty of examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

$ \psmatrix[colsep=1.5cm,rowsep=1.5cm]
        &  H^0(B)   & H^0(B)    &     \\
H^1(C)   &           &           & H^0(C)     \\
        &  H^1(A)   & H^1(B)    &     
\endpsmatrix
\psset{nodesep=3pt,arrows=->}
\ncline{2,1}{1,2}\naput{\delta_1}
\ncline{1,2}{1,3}\naput{f_0}
\ncline{1,3}{2,4}\naput{g_0}
\ncline{2,4}{3,3}\naput{\delta_0}
\ncline{3,3}{3,2}\naput{f_1}
\ncline{3,2}{2,1}\naput{g_1}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this, i like how you can see in the text how it's going to look when compiled. Pretty cool.