# Creating a cyclic graph whose nodes are row vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you produce the following exact hexagon?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29152/how-would-you-produce-the-following-exact-hexagon)

I'd like to create a hexagonal graph, where the nodes are row vectors and the edges arrows with labels (I'm trying to illustrate a cycle). See my attempt below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=0.2pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,semithick]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,draw=none,text=black]

  \node[state]         (A)                    {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (B) [below right of=A] {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below of=B]       {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below left of=C]  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (E) [above left of=D]  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (F) [above of = E]     {$(1,1,1)$};

  \path (A) edge          node {$A$} (B)
        (B) edge          node {$A$} (C)
        (C) edge          node {$A$} (D)
        (D) edge          node {$A$} (E)
        (E) edge          node {$A$} (F)
        (F) edge          node {$A$} (A);   

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want it to be a regular hexagon, which this is not. I also want the ends of the arrows to be closer to the nodes. How can I sort this?

Thanks

Comment: [Related questions containing hexagon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hexagon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use absolute coordinates and play with the directions that the x and y unit vectors point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=0.2pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,semithick,x={(1,0)},y={({cos(60)},{sin(60)})}]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,draw=none,text=black]
  \node[state] (A) at (0,0)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (B) at (3,0)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (C) at (3,3)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (D) at (0,6)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (E) at (-3,6) {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (F) at (-3,3) {$(1,1,1)$};
  \path (A) edge node {$A$} (B)
        (B) edge node {$A$} (C)
        (C) edge node {$A$} (D)
        (D) edge node {$A$} (E)
        (E) edge node {$A$} (F)
        (F) edge node {$A$} (A);   

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** If you want the hexagon "standing on a corner", you can use this instead:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=0.2pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,semithick,x={({cos(30)*1cm},{sin(30)*1cm})},y={({cos(150)*1cm},{sin(150)*1cm})}]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,draw=none,text=black]
  \node[state] (A) at (0,0)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (B) at (3,0)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (C) at (6,3)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (D) at (6,6)  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (E) at (3,6) {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state] (F) at (0,3) {$(1,1,1)$};
  \path (A) edge node {$A$} (B)
        (B) edge node {$A$} (C)
        (C) edge node {$A$} (D)
        (D) edge node {$A$} (E)
        (E) edge node {$A$} (F)
        (F) edge node {$A$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that I had to add `*1cm` as tikz shows some weird behaviour: while some of the dimensions given are interpreted as *points*, others are interpreted as *centimeters*. Delete the four `*1cm` and see for yourself!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `node distance` in both directions independently. I have approximated the double of sine and cosine values. Also the extra space is reduced by `inner sep` and `outer sep` options. If required you can give some negative number to the `shorten` option for some more extension.

I have cleaned the code a little bit and added another TikZ library, `positioning`. Notice the difference between your `above of=C` and my `above = of C`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=0.2pt,auto,%
    node distance=1cm and 1.7cm,%
    semithick,%
    every state/.style={fill=none,draw=none,text=black, outer sep=1pt, inner sep=0}%
    ]
  \node[state]         (A)                    {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (B) [below right = of A] {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below = of B]       {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below left = of C]  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (E) [above left = of D]  {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node[state]         (F) [above = of E]     {$(1,1,1)$};

  \path (A) edge          node {$A$} (B)
        (B) edge          node {$A$} (C)
        (C) edge          node {$A$} (D)
        (D) edge          node {$A$} (E)
        (E) edge          node {$A$} (F)
        (F) edge          node {$A$} (A);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I change the nodes so that they aren't all the same, it becomes a bit wonky. How can I fix that?

Comment: It is due to the relative positioning, you can use a simple `foreach` loop to place the nodes with a better precision such as `\foreach \t in {1,...,6}{\node[state] (State\t) at (90-60*\t:2) {$10253453\t$};};` (I just included a long number). Then, you don't need to adjust any `node distance` option. For labels, you can add to the `foreach` list as a second variable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also adding this solution because it's a bit more concise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=0.2pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,semithick]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,draw=none,text=black]

  \draw
  \foreach \angle/\label in {0/A,60/B,120/C,180/D,240/E,300/F}{
      (\angle:3cm) node(\label)[state]  {$(1,1,1)$}
  }
  \foreach \start/\destination in {A/B,B/C,C/D,D/E,E/F,F/A} {
      (\start) edge          node {$A$} (\destination)
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```